# How should files like blackbox logs be included?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Blackbox logs could easily be shared with a link to for example Google Drive, but if the user that shares them moves or deletes them, the link would stop working. Is there a better way that we can share those files? Should we try to avoid including them in questions at all, or should we just accept the fact that the links won't work for ever?

Answer (score 1):

This similar question was asked as a feature request on Meta Stack Exchange (the main meta for all Stack Exchange sites):

- [Please add a system to allow file uploads attached to questions and answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4637/707129)

The answer is:

> There are [lots of free file hosts](http://www.smashingapps.com/2009/05/22/6-more-free-file-hosting-websites-that-would-be-useful.html) you can use -- it puts us in a difficult position to be hosting arbitrary files for user.

Google Drive is a good file hosting option as it is extremely unlikely to go down and for the file/link to rot unless the user deletes them.

The options:

- We can encourage users to not delete the files

**OR**

- Upload all of these files to a shared Drones.SE Drive folder to keep the files alive

What does everyone else think?